# applescript oneliner

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to join applescript lines into one (in ruby it can be done using `;`)?

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to have a chunk of commands that you can execute on demand?

Comment: I asked this a year ago, it is a bit hard to remember exactly :) Thought I think it was about using `osascript -e …`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not really. The most that can be done is to take a simple `if-then` statement and make it into one line...

```
if (variable) then 
    return true
end if
```

...becomes...

```
if (variable) then return true
```

If you were to include the `osascript` command in a shell script, then multiple line scripts must delimited with `-e`...

```
osascript -e 'if (variable) then' -e 'return true' -e 'end if'
```

But that's about the extent of it. Applescript files aren't straightforward text files like most other programming languages (unfortunately) and we have to rely on its specialized editors for line management.

Comment: +1 for multiple `-e` statements, never thought of doing that. Thanks! (In my case, I wanted to embed a chunk of AppleScript in a Makefile recipe, which doesn't deal with newlines too well...)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your code.

When you use AppleScript for GUI scripting, you can often write a bunch of nested tell blocks as one line.

For example these nested tell blocks:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        tell window "System Preferences"
            tell scroll area 1
                tell button "General"
                    click
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

They could also be written as:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Preferences" to tell window "System Preferences" to tell scroll area 1 to tell button "General" to click
```

Comment: This may be helpful for people who get here from search, but still this doesn't allow to join those two tell calls into one line

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid `-e` and force everything on one line you can push everything through `echo`

```
osascript -e "`echo -e \"tell application \\"MyApp\\"\nactivate\nend tell\"`"
```

Where `"` become `\\"` and newlines become `\n`.

Comment: This is unnecessary. Just `osascript -e $'tell application "MyApp"\nactivate\nend tell'` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-arranged AppleScript from a block format, to a single line format as such:

Block format

```
tell application <application>
  activate
  open location <url>
end tell
```

Single line format

`osascript -e "tell application \"<application>\" to activate & open location \"<url>\"";`