# Insert a variable in-between ' ' in a shell osascript command?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, applescript, zsh

I am using a *MacOS* [**`osascript` command**](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html) in a shell script and I try to run the following command:

```
APPNAME=$@

if pgrep -x "$APPNAME" > /dev/null # checking if app is open
then
  echo "Closing..."
  osascript -e 'quit app $APPNAME'

else
  echo "*** The app is not open"
fi
```

Ideally, the command would be `osascript -e 'quit app "Calendar"'` as an example of a working solution. However, I can't seem to insert a variable in-between ' ' quotation marks.

What would be a workaround?

Comment: See [Process Management](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) for how to do this sort of thing properly.

Comment: @DaniilGannota: Why are you using single quotes when you don't want interpolation to occur? Aside from the obvious solution `osascript -e "quit app $APPNAME"`, an easy-to-read alternative, which might come handy if you want to do one day a mixture of interpolated and non-interpolated strings, is `osascript -e 'quit app '"$APPNAME"` .

Comment: @user1934428 I tried both these but they throw me an error! I get errors -2740, -2741 and -2743. That's why I am asking here :) Apparently, this method worked for me: `osascript -e 'on run argv' -e 'quit app (item 1 of argv)' -e 'end run' "$appname"`

Comment: Closers:  **not a duplicate** -- see [*chepner's* comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62073282/how-to-insert-a-variable-in-between-in-a-shell-command/62075148?noredirect=1#comment109786499_62073343) and [OP's follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62073282/how-to-insert-a-variable-in-between-in-a-shell-command/62075148?noredirect=1#comment109786780_62073343).  This is a miscategorized Apple specific question, **not** a *nix question..

Comment: @DaniilGannota: If you want to pass double quotes literally to osascript (which would be an odd requirement, but not inconceivable), you have of course to include them in the command: `osascript -e 'quit app "'"$APPNAME"'"'`. I just show the general principle of how to handle quoting. You need to apply this in the way it fits for your concrete usage case.

Comment: @DaniilGannota, Re *"I get errors -2740, -2741 and -2743."*: Please include the complete text of any error messages in the question.  Do not just say *"it doesn't work"* -- be specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to build a script dynamically using string interpolation is always fragile. You should pass the app name as an *argument* to the AppleScript, so that you don't have to worry about escaping any characters through two levels of interpreters.

```
APPNAME=$1  # The name should be passed as a single argument.

if pgrep -x "$APPNAME" > /dev/null # checking if app is open
then
  echo "Closing..."
  osascript -e 'on run argv' -e 'quit app (item 1 of argv)' -e 'end run' "$APPNAME"

else
  echo "*** The app is not open"
fi
```

No matter what the value of `APPNAME` is, you are executing the exact same script; the only difference is the argument that script receives.

Answer (score 1):

The point (one of the points, anyway) of single quotes is to prevent variable interpolation.  It sounds like what you really want is a way to get double quotes into a string.  There are lots of ways to do that.  A common one is:

```
osascript -e "quit app \"$appname\""
```

Comment: Cross your fingers that `appname` doesn't contain a double quote :) The safe version is something like `osascript -e 'on run argv' -e 'quit app (item 1 of argv)' -e 'end run' "$appname"` (there may be a slightly shorter way to specify a multiline script; I don't know if there's an AppleScript equivalent for `;` like `bash` uses.)

Comment: [Apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108808/applescript-oneliner), though since the question is tagged `bash` and `zsh`, something like `osascript -e $'on run argv\nquit app (item 1 of argv)\nend run' textedit` is an option. (Moral of the story: don't use parameterized "one-liners" in AppleScript.)

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run it `syntax error: A identifier can’t go after this number. (-2740)`. Do you know why?

Comment: @chepner as I am very inexperienced with shell commands, I am not entirely sure what you did there, but it worked! Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 0):

This implementation worked for me:

```
osascript -e 'quit app "'"$APPNAME"'"'
```

Trying this using:

```
osascript -e 'quit app "\"$APPNAME\""'
```

did not work resulting in error showing: "\"$APPNAME\""... as the value it is seeing.

See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251633896 for more

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
osascript -e 'quit app '"$APPNAME"
```

Or, if `osascript` requires additional double quotes, try:

```
osascript -e 'quit app "'"$APPNAME"'"'
```

Comment: For some reason the latter example is easier to keep straight in my head than the backslash `\"` equivalent -- while writing it anyway. Reading it later on it looks equally obscure.

Comment: This is still fragile: your second one assumes that `$APPNAME` itself doesn't contain double quotes.

Comment: @chepner, Re *"fragile"*: Thanks, I'm not up on *MacOS* quoting, so I'll probably delete this answer soon.

Comment: This isn't unique to macOS; you have the same problem on any platform. The bigger problem here is that you are nesting one script inside another script, which just multiplies the quoting concerns.

Comment: @chepner, In that case it's unclear what *"your second one assumes ... double quotes"* is warning against.  This works `f='"dquote"' ; echo "$f"`, so if used carefully what is fragile there?  (Agreed however, that minimizing quoting is preferable.)

Comment: Say `APPNAME='Weird"AppName'`. Then `osascript` will see the argument `quit app Weird"AppName`, which contains an unclosed double-quote. You would have to make sure that `AppName` contained a fragment of AppleScript that *represents* the application's name when incorporated into the surrounding context, rather than simply the application's name.